# IE8 how to hide "Java is obsolete" bar message preventing automatic script execution?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, java-applet, sun-java6-jdk

I have a computer which specifically needs to use Java 6 Update 11 **AND** IE8. (Updating to Java 7 Update 67 crashes all the web apps of my customer).

I uninstalled the new Java and installed his old version again but the Java Applets execution are now prevented instead of starting automatically: IE shows a toolbar message saying "Java is obsolete..." and the user must click the bar and choose "Execute once" to run the applet.

There are no "Always Execute" option or anything alike.

Is there a way to force the automatic execution of the applets by hiding this warning message?

Comment: I feel your pain.

Comment: I wish there was a simple solution. Sometimes business apps can be so complicated for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try to push below settings into all affected machines

> > Turn off blocking of outdated ActiveX controls for Internet Explorer
> >
> > "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Ext" 
> >     /v VersionCheckEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

If none of the above options work, the address of the site which needs to use an out-of-date Java ActiveX control can be added to the >>**Trusted Sites zone**.

Reference : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/08/06/internet-explorer-begins-blocking-out-of-date-activex-controls.aspx

Comment: I wonder why this answer wasn't either upvoted nor accepted... It solved the problem for me. Thanks! :)